# OOP Java BlueJ, Cannot Find Symbol - Variable X

Tags: java, variables, symbols, bluej

So I'm studying from a book without an Answer Key and I'm stuck with this question as I just started Java and the question states "Develop a new class called BankAccount. A bank account has an owner’s name and a balance. Be sure to include a constructor that allows a client to supply the owner’s name and an initial balance. A bank account needs accessors for the name and balance, mutators for making deposits and withdrawals, and a toString method. Test-drive your new class with a program similar to the one used to test the Student class". I actually did write the code but I get an error as I'm using BlueJ. It states the following "Cannot Find Symbol - Variable (The Variable You've entered)." Here's the code:

```
public class BankAccount {

public String owner;
public float balance;

public BankAccount(String owner, float balance) {
    this.owner = owner;
    this.balance = balance;
}

public void deposit(float amount) {
    balance += amount;
}
public void withdraw(float amount) {
    balance -= amount;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Owner: " + owner + ", balance: " + balance;
}       

}
```

Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner and I may have made a silly mistake. I'm new to BlueJ too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get any further information with the error?

Answer (score 0):

I can not add a comment to your post, because of reputation. But try to check this, if you don't have a mistake in another class which is calling the method.
Kinda the same [problem](http://forums.udacity.com/questions/100085070/bluej-error-cannot-find-symbol-variable-nameperson)  I think.
And your variables should be private or protected because of encapsulation :) . It depends how you want to use them.

```
private String owner;
private float balance;
```

Hope it helped a bit. :)